# Inserting to database efficiently by removing repeated code

Tags: java, cassandra, performance

I have started working with `Cassandra database` recently. And I was trying to insert some data into one of my `Column Family` that I have created.

Below is the code by which I am trying to insert into Cassandra Database.

In my case I have around `20 columns` in my column family so that means I need to add below line

`mutator.newColumn("Column Name", "Column Value");`

**twenty times** in my below code which looks ugly to me. Is there any way, I can simplify the below method either by using reflection or some other way so that If I have more than 20  columns, I should not keep on adding extra line in my below code.

```
for (int userId = id; userId < id + noOfTasks; userId++) {

    Mutator mutator = Pelops.createMutator(thrift_connection_pool);

    mutator.writeColumns(column_family, String.valueOf(userId),
            mutator.newColumnList(
            mutator.newColumn("a_account", "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"regSiteId\":null,\"userState\":null,\"userId\":" + userId + "},\"cn\":1}],\"lmd\":20130206211109}"), 
            mutator.newColumn("a_advertising", "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"regSiteId\":null,\"userState\":null,\"userId\":" + userId + "},\"cn\":1}],\"lmd\":20130206211109}"), 
            mutator.newColumn("a_avg_selling_price_main_cats", "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"regSiteId\":null,\"userState\":null,\"userId\":" + userId + "},\"cn\":1}],\"lmd\":20130206211109}"), 
            mutator.newColumn("a_cat_and_keyword_rules", "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"regSiteId\":null,\"userState\":null,\"userId\":" + userId + "},\"cn\":1}],\"lmd\":20130206211109}"), 
            mutator.newColumn("a_csa_categories_purchased", "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"regSiteId\":null,\"userState\":null,\"userId\":" + userId + "},\"cn\":1}],\"lmd\":20130206211109}"), 
            mutator.newColumn("a_customer_service", "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"regSiteId\":null,\"userState\":null,\"userId\":" + userId + "},\"cn\":1}],\"lmd\":20130206211109}"), 
            mutator.newColumn("a_demographic", "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"regSiteId\":null,\"userState\":null,\"userId\":" + userId + "},\"cn\":1}],\"lmd\":20130206211109}"), 
            mutator.newColumn("a_favorite_searches", "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"regSiteId\":null,\"userState\":null,\"userId\":" + userId + "},\"cn\":1}],\"lmd\":20130206211109}"), 
            mutator.newColumn("a_favorite_sellers", "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"regSiteId\":null,\"userState\":null,\"userId\":" + userId + "},\"cn\":1}],\"lmd\":20130206211109}"), 
            mutator.newColumn("a_financial", "{\"lv\":[{\"v\":{\"regSiteId\":null,\"userState\":null,\"userId\":" + userId + "},\"cn\":1}],\"lmd\":20130206211109}")
            mutator.newColumn(some othe column, its value)
            .....
            .....
            .....
            ));


    mutator.execute(ConsistencyLevel.ONE);
}
```

Any help in simplifying the above method will be of great help to me. May be I can use reflection here? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can predefine your ColumnList.  Let's say you pass in a map of names and string versions of values in a variable named "map".  Your code might look like this:

```
Mutator mutator = Pelops.createMutator(thrift_connection_pool);
ArrayList<Column> columnList = new ArrayList<Column>();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    columnList.add(mutator.newColumn(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
}
mutator.writeColumns(column_family, String.valueOf(userId), columnList);
```